# Joinig multiple tables in django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am newbie django learner and  I am working on my semester project, that has database structure like this:[lines represent relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPA5l.jpg)

Here lines joining represent relationships between them.
Now, I want to generate report like shown below from this database.
[Desired Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dml3.jpg)

I can not figure out how to achieve this, any help will be appreciated, regards.

Comment: Sounds like you should read up on Django's foreign keys. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Instead of images please add models. And for the report have you tried making any query ?

Comment: @AKX ,  I am going through it . But can not figure it how to combine these queries .